# Different charges of plates of parallel plate capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance

Suppose the plates of a parallel plate capacitor have charges +2Q and -Q initially.

Then if they are connected with a battery of emf V what will be the charge distribution on the plates of capacitor?

I tried it by initially getting the charge distribution. But when the battery is connected i am getting confused.

Comment: Same as with zero initial charge plus 0.5Q on each plate

Comment: What is capacitance, initially,charge is Q what intial voltage ,it look incomplete to me

Answer (score 2):

Start off by considering what the charge distribution would be like without the battery being connected.
The charge distribution must be such that there is no electric field inside either of the plates.
The consider which of the charges will change when the battery is connected.

Comment: Do we need the value of the capacitance then, also the voltage?@Farcher

Comment: The capacitance is a function of the geometry of the system of plates not the charges on them.

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect the capacitor to the battery the voltage across the capacitor must the the same as that of the battery. Once you know the voltage across the capacitor you can calculate the charge distribution.

What is the role of the extra initial charge on the plates? Nothing, because the extra charges will be quickly killed by the holes and the electrons of the battery.